she will be / she is

Capuchins ― New World Monkeys that live in large social groups ― will, in captivity, trade with people all day long, especially if food is involved. I give you this rock and you give me a treat to eat. If you put two monkeys in cages next to each other, and offer them both slices of cucumber for the rocks they already have, they will happily eat the cucumbers. If, however, you give one monkey grapes instead ― grapes being universally preferred to cucumbers ― the monkey that is still receiving cucumbers will begin to throw them back at the experimenter. Even though she is still getting “paid” the same amount for her effort of sourcing rocks, and so her particular situation has not changed, the comparison to another makes the situation unfair. Furthermore, she is now willing to abandon all gains ― the cucumbers themselves ― to communicate her displeasure to the experimenter.

*source; ‘A Hunter-Gatherer's Guide to the 21st Century’ by Heather Heying & Bret Weinstein
When I rewrite the bold part above, which verb form will be grammatically fit between two options below, while I prefer ‘will be’, since I think this ‘will’ as a modal expresses the subject’s willingness to do something?;
(A) She(the monkey) will be upset by the unfairness.
(B) She is upset by the unfairness.
Would appreciate your responses.

Will here does not mean willingness. It's simply the future tense of the verb to be. Choose the tense that makes most sense to you. In that paragraph they will both work. If you pay close attention to the tenses while reading it through, you will see a regular switch between present and future.

In this sentence, as well as in that paragraph they [will] both work. But personally I'd advise learners to choose by default the simplest verb form that works (forget about other more exotic forms that will [also] work).

@Peter Kirkpatrick Appreciate your response. While I understand we use the simple present form to express 1) permanent states, 2) general truths, 3) habitual actions, 4) live commentary, 5) performative actions, 6) past time or historic present, and 7) future time, then which case does your suggested simple present form fall into?

@FumbleFingers Appreciate your response. While I understand we use the simple present form to express 1) permanent states, 2) general truths, 3) habitual actions, 4) live commentary, 5) performative actions, 6) past time or historic present, and 7) future time, then which case does your suggested simple present form fall into?

Present tense in the cited context probably represents your category 2 or 3, but since the same verb form (the simplest) covers all those possibilities, it doesn't really make any difference from the perspective of native speakers. We only have to be aware of "special cases" where the default Present Tense either doesn't work at all or fails to convey some relevant nuance. Notice how the text includes the monkey that is still receiving cucumbers will begin to throw them back (not begins). Peter's comment notwithstanding, I see an element of "willful volition" there.

Why are you rewriting a text? What's your point.

@Lambie Recently I'm reading 'tense' part in a grammar book. When I saw the passage above, a question hit on me about 'she will be / she is'.

You're not predicting her behavior but explaining its cause, so the simple predicate is is preferable:

She is upset by the unfairness.

You're stating a "general truth" about Capuchin behavior.
The sentence you're rewriting also uses the simple present, makes, for this reason.

I. Simple Present Tense usage.
Ref. Cambridge dictionary.

We use the present simple to talk about regular or habitual events.

First let's consider the reason why Simple Present is normally used for explaining an experiment (instead of Simple Past )

To show that you will get the same results every time.
It is the preferred tense for writing a procedure to be followed.
It simplifies the description.
To show it is universal truth.

II. Conclusion/ Result of an experiment:.
Now coming to OP's query:

(A) She(the monkey) will be upset by the unfairness.
(B) She is upset by the unfairness.    .

This is the result/ findings of the experiment. Normally the result is  written in Simple Past.
For example:

The experiment showed that monkeys become upset when rewarded unequally

In OP's case either A or B: could be used.
A) She will be upset

to show predictable behaviour

B) She is upset.

Aligns with the flow of the passage.
Also shows consistent behaviour. (The experiment was carried between different sets of monkeys and the same behaviour was observed)

